# Git on Windows -- all Git clients use the same config stack, right?

Tags: git

I am being asked which Git client I use:

https://gitforwindows.org/
or
https://git-scm.com/download/win

I had the understanding that the core git library is always used, and uses the same configuration files, global to the whole user session (except for in-session-overridden env vars).

Am I right?

(My uncertainty comes from the fact that a "git administrator" is asking me, and is shaking my earlier certainty.)

Comment: What in god's name is a "git adminstrator"?

Comment: @MattMessersmith The guy who manages our central git installation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These two are the same thing. Just different sites pointing to the same git client, built from the same source code:

> https://github.com/git-for-windows/git

Compare the download links, and you'll see that they all point to releases in the GitHub repo. e.g. `https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.19.0.windows.1/Git-2.19.0-64-bit.exe`

Answer (score 1):

Those two are built from git's source code and stuff... but other clients use libgit2 and that's a completely different implementation so no warranties for other clients.

PS Those two are the same, right? I was thinking of git for windows and git through cygwin.... anyway.